# Jmeter request and report validation

Tags: jmeter

My Requirement is to **execute 10 request per second for 5 minutes**. The configuration I have used is

**Thread Group Properties:**
number of threads : 600
ramp up period : 60
Loop count : 5,
**Add Sampler -> Flow Control Action**
Select Logical Action on thread as Pause
Duration(milliseconds) :60000

I used the below command to run jmx from command line to generate xls and generate html report.

```
/jmeter.sh -n -t demo.jmx -l demo.xls -e -o ./report
```

Need to know if the configuration I have mapped is correct or not?
I have also looked at constant throughput timer and Runtime controller to stop the execution after 5 mins?
I am not able to validate the end result?

Answer (score 0):

You can see what actual throughput your test generated using [Transactions Per Second](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/TransactionsPerSecond/) listener or the [relevant chart](https://jmeter.apache.org/images/screenshots/dashboard/report_transactions_per_second.png) in the [HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html)

With regards to configuring JMeter for sending 10 requests per second for 5 minutes I would rather recommend going for [Concurrency Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/) and [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/) combination.

Configurations:

[image]

[image]